# Como criar uma constraint de Primary Key nomeada no Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraint

Estou prosseguindo assim para criar uma tabela sem chave primária, inicialmente.  Depois eu adiciono um campo `id` do tipo serial e tento criar a *constraint* para a *Primary Key* (PK):

```
create table macaco(
  nome varchar(50),
  idade integer
);

--adicionando o id do tipo serial
ALTER TABLE "macaco" ADD COLUMN id SERIAL;

--criando a primary key 
ALTER TABLE "macaco" ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Do modo como eu faço acima, ele cria a PK com o nome de `macaco_pkey`.
Até aí tudo bem. Mas e se eu quiser criar a *constraint* com o nome `id_macaco_pk`, o que devo fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você quer é este comando:

```
ALTER TABLE macaco ADD CONSTRAINT id_macaco_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no SQLFiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a3e98)

Comment: Obriagado cara, ajudou bastante!